# Is the sum of the circulant matrix with a super upper triangular matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

By the circulant matrix $C$ in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, we mean that
$$C=[e_n|e_1|\cdots|e_{n-1}]$$ where $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ are the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  It is well-known that
$$C=\mathbf{F}\operatorname{Diag}(1,w,\cdots,w^{n-1})\mathbf{F}^{-1}$$
where $\mathbf{F}$ is just the discrete Fourier matrix and $w=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n})$

Let $U=(u_{ij})$ be a upper triangular matrix. We say it is supper upper triangular if  $u_{i, i+1}=0$.

Let $U$ be a supper upper triangular   whose entries are either 0 or 1.
Is $C+U$  diagonalizable?

Comment: That circulant matrix is also a permutation matrix

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo, Yes. If it would be valid, one may think about the extension on a larger category of matrices containing the circulant matrix.

Comment: Since $\bf F$ is unitary, its inverse is easy to compute

Comment: Yes, the inverse is just the transpose.

Comment: Hermitian transpose

Comment: You mean, upper triangular with zero diagonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: For $U$ take
$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
0& 0 &0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 0 &0 &1& 0& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 0 &0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1\\
0& 0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1\\
0& 0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Then the rational canonical form of $C+U$ is
$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 &-1&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0  &0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0  &0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0  &0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0  &0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0  &0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 0  &0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 4& -2 & 2
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Comment: If you want to check this, here's some Magma code:

Q:=Rationals();

M:=MatrixAlgebra(Q,8);

U:=M![ 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];

C:=M![
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0, 
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0, 
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0, 
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0, 
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0, 
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0, 
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

JordanForm(C+U);

Comment: Thanks, it is so helpful.

Comment: If you want to know how I found this, it was actually a rather stupid method. I tried Random(0,1) examples on Magma, starting with $n=4$ and gradually increasing until an example appeared. Nothing clever at all.

Comment: Actually, your suggestion made me move forward in a research project, related to graph signal processing!

Comment: @ABB : ----- Nice!